# Which is the suitable Ram Card to add memory for my laptop?

Tags: memory

I have a sony e series model `sve1513acnb` with 2 Gb ram & i3 Processor I want to add 2 Gb Ram Memory but I am confused. Which is the best Memory Card is suitable for my laptop?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your laptop has DDR3 version of RAM with 2GB of memory. You can buy the new transcend or any other superior model RAM with 2 GB of memory and install it in your system on the unused slot for the RAM on your laptop motherboard. For example you can  refer this link to check on the specification of the RAM 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Transcend-JetRAM-2GB-DDR3-1333MHz-PC3-10600-CL9-So-DIMM-SDRAM-Laptop-RAM-Module-/160715116200

Answer (score 0):

This type of questions are considered as off topic as this is purely opinion based, but still the best thing is open your laptop see the brand of RAM which is already there in your laptop and also see the frequency of your RAM and purchase the same one.

That will give best performance as everything(ie, frequency) will be matched and you don't have to bother about anything else.